# does compiling c++ to assembly give performance?

Tags: c++, assembly

I wanted to post a question in the site while my question fully fits in rules
it errors

This is my question(is it possible to convert c++ code to assembly or to machine code to gain performance?
i know lower level languages are faster to run on hardware because of direct accessing to hardware while higher level languages need to compile
so my idea is to compile c++ codes once and save and run the compiled version
is it practical?
i have heard that it requires a 1-1 compiler does such thing exist?)

Comment: How are you running your C++ programs now, if not by using a compiler?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of a question I remember from a few months ago, which I can't find ATM.  It was also asking about explicitly compiling C to assembly with gcc and then assembling, instead of the default of compiling+assembling in the same step (again not realizing that this is what happens.  Some C/C++ compilers output machine code directly instead of ever generating text asm behind the scenes, but that's a 1:1 process).

Comment: Not only is it possible, that is exactly what your C++ compiler is doing.

Comment: As other comments say, it is exactly what happens when you pass your C++ code through the compiler to get an assembly listing or direct binary machine code.  In fact, the use of compilers is basically that, not having to interpret the code each time you want to run your program.

Answer (score 7):

C++ is (almost) always compiled to assembly before executing anyway. So it can't be *not* converted to assembly and therefore the question doesn't really make sense. Of course, you could translate it to assembly and then optimize it, but there's very very very few cases where this actually increases performance (and you have to really know what you're doing). Usually, its much easier to start optimizing the C++ code instead (i.e. by reducing the number of loops required or adding caches).

Comment: Technically of course, it is *possible* to compile C++ to Java bytecode, and then have the JVM interpret it, but usually the only reason to do that is to prove you can.

Comment: @MartinBonner: Of course. That's actually what C++/CLI is regularly doing (and there are true applications for that, such as interfacing to unmanaged code), but then even the byte code is often not interpreted any more but just-in-time compiled.

Comment: That is a crime to the creators of C++, they would cry if they knew someone converted nice, beautiful C++ code into Java code

Comment: @TomDoodler: Not java code, java byte code. That's basically a machine-independent low-level language.

Comment: @PMF, option `-S` indeed, generates an assembler listing of the generated code. Many compilers in the un*x environment run the compiler that first generates assembler code and then run the assembler to generate binary code.  This two phase approach allows analysing the generated code by humans, detect compiler errors and modify the code previous to encode as binary code.

Answer (score 3):

Unmanaged language like C/C++ doesn't have runtime engine like managed language do have (C#, Java). The C++ code would be compiled by compiler, which would generate *object* files (called intermediate files). Then these object files would be read by linker to produce one *executable* file (in general sense).

The executable (or DLL/SO) contains **native instructions** that would be processed directly by the processor. So, if you compile a program to 32-bit (x86), the set of instructions produced by compiler/linker would be formed of x86 CPU instruction set only - no runtime engine involved.

Hence, bringing assembly-code doesn't make sense. ASM code may be generated by compiler just for the programmer to know what is generated (as a text file, for e.g.)

Comment: Based on the level of the question, I don't think we need to make the destinction between assembly language and machine code here.... That would confuse the OP even further, I guess ;-)

Comment: by the way, what do you mean with **managed language** ???  I'm afray you are messing concepts, talking about runtime, high level language (java can be compiled to binary code, google for "just in time compiler") and DLL (dynamic linking doesn't have nothing to do with virtual machine or real processor running-- all java code is dynamic linked, like `.dll` or `.so` concept)  Don't mess things, please.

Comment: @LuisColorado Even a JIT compiled native code would need runtime. It would still not be entirely CPU level instruction set code. No, I am not mixing concepts - I just said EXE/DLL/SO are all output. For managed, they need runtime, for unmanaged, they don't need RT.

Comment: @Ajay, that's what I say, all compiled code normally needs some kind of runtime code to prepare the environment for the program to execute. **You are mixing concepts** because runtime has nothing to do with the question at all, that is if *compiling to assembler does improve performance at all or not*.  You have begun to talk about virtual running environments, **managed languages** (without defining such a concept) the need of runtimes and dynamic linking, and that only confuses the target.

Answer (score 2):

No. When you compile your C++ Source code, it gets compiled to machine code anyway. You can either gain performance, by optimizing your C++ code or write the pice of code you want to omptimize in an assembly language, you then could optimize your code on the lowest possible level to gain performance, but simply compiling your code and then use it like that wont help.

Comment: i mean compiling during development not during running

Comment: i mean compiling during development not during running  "save the assembly version and running it instead of c++" does a c++ code compiled to assembly perform and behave like a code that is written in assembly from beginning ?

Comment: That is the same. Every code is basically "written in assembly" after it is compiled. assembly code runs faster, thats correct, but only, because it is written on the (almost) lowest level and can therefore be highly optimized. I think you didnt understand how a compiled language works, did you?

Comment: Every compiled language, C++, C, C#, F#, Basic and so on gets compiled to an executable. This consists of machine code. Assembly languages do also consist of machine code (after being assembled by an assembler). A compiler translates programming code to machine code, which is then called an "executable". Theres no difference between an executable written in C++ and one written in Assembly

Comment: as far as i now c++ compiles in runtime but not step by step  so instead during development compiling program to object files and running object files as object files are pre-compiled they only need to get linked by linker does it help? am i right?

Comment: You cant execute object files before they get linked together by the compiler. You could use the precompiled object files (maybe, dont know if thats possible) but the only advantage of that would be to save the 10 or 20 milliseconds it takes to compile that file

Comment: Actually if you are using an IDE or a makefile, files that didnt get changed since the last time they got compiled dont get compiled anyway

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to convert c++ code to assembly or to machine code

In general, every c++ compiler generates machine code for the executable. You can get a assembler file if you want.

Example on gcc:

```
 g++ -S -c main.cpp
```

this generates a `main.s` file where you can see the generated assembly like that ( present only a small snipped of main function):

```
   .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
 main:
 .LFB3028:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
    .cfi_lsda 0x3,.LLSDA3028
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16 
   .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
    .cfi_offset 3, -24 
    movl    $48, %edx
    movl    $.LC15, %esi
    subq    $552, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 576 
    leaq    32(%rsp), %rbx
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
 .LEHB3:
    call    _ZNSt14basic_ofstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEEC1EPKcSt13_Ios_Openmode
```

> to gain performance?

Not at all, because all you suggest is already done :-)

> while higher level languages need to compile so my idea is to compile c++ codes once and save and run the compiled version is it practical

That is exactly what a compiler already does! It compiles your c++ code to machine executable ( machine code ). So everything is ready to use.

You maybe can take a look at assembly output to get an idea how a particular code fragment you wrote will be run on your machine. Maybe you have a chance to write it in a better/smaller/faster way by hand. But in fact todays compilers are much better then any handcrafted code if we talk about real world applications. Maybe you have some time critical interrupt routines where you can save some instructions.

The scenario which you have in mind is only true for scripting languages where a textfile is pre-compiled maybe during run time or by a "compiler" before execution of your application and some kind of byte code will be executed on a run time engine of that language like in java. But that is not true for c++.